# How can i login into salesforce from salesforce let's say through apex code or REST API class

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, authentication

How can I get the session id? Can I log in into Salesforce through Apex code?

I have achieved similar functionality using Java but I am not sure how to achieve this using Apex.

Comment: People are answering, I still confused with the question. To execute apex, user should have the session. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is you can

a) Use OAuth 2.0 (userid/password) in your SFDC client Apex code to authenticate against the remote SFDC org.

b) This returns an access token and sfdc url that are used in subsequent REST calls to do SOQL or DML.

No SOAP required

Here's the APEX code to do the rest authentication and a SOQL query.  (test methods and setup of Connected Apps are covered here: http://cropredysfdc.com/2013/12/06/salesforce-to-salesforce-using-rest-part-i/ )

```
public with sharing class HttpRest {

//  Class to handle HTTP Rest calls to other SFDC instances
//
//  [HTTP-00]   - Reached limit on callouts
//  [HTTP-01]   - Unable to get OAuth 2.0 token from remote SFDC
//  [HTTP-02]   - Error in SOQL REST query

String  accessToken;                    // OAuth 2.0 access token
String  sfdcInstanceUrl;                // Endpoint URL for SFDC instance

private HttpResponse send(String uri,String httpMethod) {
    return send(uri,httpMethod,null);
}

private HttpResponse send(String uri, String httpMethod, String body) {

    if (Limits.getCallouts() == Limits.getLimitCallouts())
        throw new MyException('[HTTP-00] Callout limit: ' + Limits.getCallouts() + ' reached. No more callouts permitted.');
    Http        h       = new Http();
    HttpRequest hRqst   = new HttpRequest();
    hRqst.setEndpoint(uri);                     // caller provides, this will be a REST resource
    hRqst.setMethod(httpMethod);                // caller provides
    hRqst.setTimeout(6000); 
    if (body != null) 
        hRqst.setBody(body);                    // caller provides
    if (this.accessToken != null)               // REST requires using the token, once obtained for each request
        hRqst.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + this.accessToken);
    return h.send(hRqst);                   // make the callout
}   
//  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  authenticateByUserNamePassword      : Returns a map of <String,String> of the OAuth 2.0 access token; required before REST calls on SFDC instances can be made 
//  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void authenticateByUserNamePassword(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String uName, String uPassword, Boolean isSandbox) {
    // Reference documentation can be found in the REST API Guide, section: 'Understanding the Username-Password OAuth Authentication Flow'
    // OAuth 2.0 token is obtained from endpoints:
    //  PROD orgs   : https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
    //  SANDBOX orgs: https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

    //  OAuth 2.0 access token contains these name/values:
    //      access_token        : used in subsequent REST calls
    //      instance_url        : to form the REST URI
    //      id                  : identifies end user
    //      issued_at           : When signature was created
    //      signature           : HMAC-SHA256 signature signed with private key - can be used to verify the instance_url     

    String uri          = 'https://' + (isSandbox ? 'test' : 'login') + '.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
    String clientId     = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(consumerKey,'UTF-8');
    String clientSecret = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(consumerSecret,'UTF-8');
    String username     = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(uName,'UTF-8');
    String password     = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(uPassword,'UTF-8');

    String body =   'grant_type=password&client_id=' + clientId + 
                    '&client_secret=' + clientSecret +
                    '&username=' + username + 
                    '&password=' + password; 

    HttpResponse hRes = this.send(uri,'POST',body);
    if (hRes.getStatusCode() != 200) 
        throw new MyException('[HTTP-01] OAuth 2.0 access token request error. Verify username, password, consumer key, consumer secret, isSandbox?  StatusCode=' +
                                             hRes.getStatusCode() + ' statusMsg=' + hRes.getStatus());


    System.debug('response body =\n' + hRes.getBody());


    Map<String,String> res = (Map<String,String>) JSON.deserialize(hRes.getBody(),Map<String,String>.class);

    this.accessToken        = res.get('access_token');      // remember these for subsequent calls
    this.sfdcInstanceUrl    = res.get('instance_url');


}


//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  doSoqlQuery: Executes a REST query on a remote SFDC and returns a list of SObjects
//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
public List<SObject> doSoqlQuery(String query) {
    List<Sobject> res;        
    PageReference   urlPg   = new PageReference(this.sfdcInstanceUrl + '/services/data/v29.0/query');
    urlPg.getParameters().put('q',query); 

    String uri              = urlPg.getUrl();               // let APEX do the URL encoding of the parms as necessary
    HttpResponse hRes = this.send(uri,'GET');
    if (hRes.getStatusCode() != 200) 
        throw new MyException('[HTTP-02] Error in query ' + uri + ' StatusCode=' +
                                             hRes.getStatusCode() + ' statusMsg=' + hRes.getStatus());

    // Response body comes back as:
    // {"totalSize":10,
    //  "done":true,
    //  "records":[
    //              {"attributes":{
    //                  "type"  : "the sobject",
    //                  "url"   : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/the sobject/the id"
    //              },
    //              "field0 in query"   : "value of field 0",
    //              "field1 in query"   : "value of field1",
    //              ...},
    //              next record ...
    //              ]
    //  }
    JSONParser jp = JSON.createParser(hRes.getBody());
    do{
        jp.nextToken();
    } while(jp.hasCurrentToken() && !'records'.equals(jp.getCurrentName()));
    jp.nextToken();  // token is 'records'
    res = (List<SObject>) jp.readValueAs(List<SObject>.class);      // Let caller cast to specific SObject
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a login from Apex by using the SOAP API login method to retrieve the Session Id. You will need to add a Remote Site setting(https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0) in your org and possibly append the users security token to the end of the password for this to work.

```
public with sharing class Login {

private static final String NS_SOAP = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
private static final String NS_SF = 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com';

public static String login(String user, String password)
{
    // As per http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Enterprise_Login
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');   
    req.setTimeout(60000);
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');        
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
    req.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' +user+ '</username><password>' + password + '</password></login></Body></Envelope>');        
    HttpResponse res =  new Http().send(req);
    if(res.getStatusCode() != 200)
    {
        Dom.Document responseDocument = res.getBodyDocument();
        Dom.Xmlnode rootElm = responseDocument.getRootElement(); // soapenv:Envelope
        Dom.Xmlnode bodyElm = rootElm.getChildElement('Body', NS_SOAP); // soapenv:Body 
        Dom.Xmlnode faultElm = bodyElm.getChildElement('Fault', NS_SOAP); // soapenv:Fault
        Dom.Xmlnode faultStringElm = faultElm.getChildElement('faultstring', null); // faultstring          
        throw new LoginException(faultStringElm.getText()); 
    }
    // As per http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Enterprise_Login
    Dom.Document responseDocument = res.getBodyDocument();
    Dom.Xmlnode rootElm = responseDocument.getRootElement(); // soapenv:Envelope
    Dom.Xmlnode bodyElm = rootElm.getChildElement('Body', NS_SOAP); // soapenv:Body 
    Dom.Xmlnode loginResponseElm = bodyElm.getChildElement('loginResponse', NS_SF); // loginResponse
    Dom.Xmlnode resultElm = loginResponseElm.getChildElement('result', NS_SF); // result
    Dom.Xmlnode sessionIdElm = resultElm.getChildElement('sessionId', NS_SF); // sessionId
    return sessionIdElm.getText();
}

public class LoginException extends Exception {}
}
```

Comment: It works fine in my developer org but when i run the same in sandbox it gives me an error:
Login.LoginException: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
I am passing the correct user name and password along with security token.Is there anything i need to change in sandbox?

Comment: The user is locked. Go to user detail page and click unlock then it works fine.

Comment: @sunny Could you elaborate on this part: "append the users security token to the end of the password for this to work."? Is this done in the Apex code? How do you access the user's access token from within Apex?

Comment: @JWiley : Just create a string in apex with combination of your password with security token. Or Store it in custom settings.

Comment: +1 for the answer...I did not use security token. But still got the session ID... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing Apex code (not as a batch job) then you can refer to UserInfo.getSessionID() to return your session ID.

e.g.

```
System.debug(UserInfo.getSessionID());
```

Comment: I am executing my REST API Class method through scheduler class where i am passing the session id.But when i am not logged in into the instance my scheduler class doesn't run.To avoid this i was thinking if i can log in into salesforce through code and get the session id.In this way i can pass the session id dynamically.

Comment: To execute APEX code to get a session ID you need to be logged into Salesforce.

Comment: I will call the SOAP API login method in scheduler class which will give me the session id which inturn i will pass to the future method.